# How do you set a Translate Transform to an ImageBrush within a Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

I have the following simple path.  But everytime in Expression Blend I try and set a translate transform to its image brush the image disappears.  Ideally the fill should be none.  I need to dynamicly set the x and y of the image within the brush if possible.  If you have done this in C# that would be fine as well.  Or am I mistaken and this just cant be done?

```
<Path Data="M0.5,0.5 L99.5,0.5 L99.5,439.5 L0.5,439.5 z" Fill="#BFF31313" Height="440" Canvas.Left="192" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="176" Width="100" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="4x4.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<Path Data="M0.5,0.5 L99.5,0.5 L99.5,439.5 L0.5,439.5 z" Fill="#BFF31313" Height="440" Canvas.Left="192" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="176" Width="100" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="4x4.png" Stretch="None">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TranslateTransform X="10" Y="10"/>
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Comment: Very strange, don't know why Expression blend wouldn't create that for me.  But thats the money, thanks!